# Unique Word Extraction

Tags: c#, cpu-word, unique

Hello Friends: i have a list of words separated by Comma"," .e.g  Location, Organization,Person, Location, Person,Date,Organization,Date,Location,Person.
Now my problems is that how to extract unique words e.g Location,Organization, Person,date 
out of the above listed words and after extraction how to store these unique words in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some LINQ:

```
var words = "Location, Organization,Person, Location, Person,Date,Organization,Date,Location,Person";
var uniqueWords = words.Split(',')
                       .Select(word => word.Trim())
                       .Where(word => word.Length > 0)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToArray();
```

If, additionally, you want to ignore the case of the words, you could use: `.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` (or a different comparer that suits your needs).